# Screen state goes back whenever i Click a sprite

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to make a game in Xna 4.0 and im stuck with the game menu.

```cs
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();

        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        if (ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && ((ms.X >= 280 && ms.X <= 540) && (ms.Y >= 150 && ms.Y <= 200)))
            current_screen = ScreenState.Difficulty;

        if (current_screen == ScreenState.Title)
        {
            if (ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && ((ms.X >= 280 && ms.X <= 540) && (ms.Y >= 360 && ms.Y <= 410)))
                this.Exit();
        }

        if (current_screen == ScreenState.Difficulty)
        {
            if (ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && ((ms.X >= 300 && ms.X <= 520) && (ms.Y >= 100 && ms.Y <= 130)))
                current_screen = ScreenState.Title;
            if ((ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released) && ((ms.X >= 280 && ms.X <= 540) && (ms.Y >= 150 && ms.Y <= 200)))
            {
                current_screen = ScreenState.MainGameNovice;
            }
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
        oldMouseState = ms;
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        switch (current_screen)
        {
            case ScreenState.Title:
                spriteBatch.Draw(mybg, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.Draw(new_game_button, new Vector2(280, 150), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.Draw(load_game_button, new Vector2(280, 220), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.Draw(how_to_play_button, new Vector2(280, 290), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.Draw(quit_game_button, new Vector2(280, 360), Color.White);
                break;

            case ScreenState.Difficulty:
                spriteBatch.Draw(diff_bg, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.Draw(novice_button, new Vector2(280, 150), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.Draw(inter_button, new Vector2(280, 220), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.Draw(expert_button, new Vector2(280, 290), Color.White);
                break;

            case ScreenState.LoadGame:
                break;

            case ScreenState.HowtoPlay:
                break;

            case ScreenState.MainGameNovice:
                //main game
                spriteBatch.Draw(expert_button, new Vector2(580, 290), Color.White);
                break;

            case ScreenState.MainGameIntermediate:
                ///main game
                break;

            case ScreenState.MainGameExpert:
                ////Main game
                break;
        }

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Whenever I click the new game button, it would show the difficulty level.
The problem is when I click the novice button it won't go to the screen that looks like a plain blue screen. It goes through it and in just a matter of seconds it will go back to the difficulty level menu. Can you please help me? I've been stuck here for about a day, I 've searched for problems similar to this but still wont work.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have the same call twice in your update.

Look at your difficulty statement:

```
if (ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && ((ms.X >= 280 && ms.X <= 540) && (ms.Y >= 150 && ms.Y <= 200)))
    current_screen = ScreenState.Difficulty;
```

And then at your novice game statement:

```
if ((ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released) && ((ms.X >= 280 && ms.X <= 540) && (ms.Y >= 150 && ms.Y <= 200)))
    {
        current_screen = ScreenState.MainGameNovice;

    }
```

Once you click the button that sets current_screen to MainGameNovice, it will immediately consider the difficulty button to be clicked since there is nothing that prevents it from running immediately after because you do not look to see if the mouse button was released since the last update. There lies your problem. Make sure your difficulty button also includes:

```
oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released
```

Comment: thanks sir for the answer. but now it shows the blue screen and skips the level of difficulty menu whenever i click the new game button. what do I do?

Comment: @user2890529 you should rethink that system. Go read something about game states if you can't make it work by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You always have to check a pressed button on the `Released` event of your mouse listener.
Change your code with this:

```cs
if (ms.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && oldMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
```

This will ensure that a click will be detected only once.

---

And as a suggestion, don't use things like these:

```cs
(ms.X >= 280 && ms.X <= 540) && (ms.Y >= 360 && ms.Y <= 410)
```

Use the `Rectangle` structure, instead, that provides a useful method called `Rectangle.Contains()`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.aspx).